# Laravel SSH read and write a file

Tags: php, xml, linux, laravel, ssh

Greeting everyone. I'm trying to read an XML file, change value and save it back, all done via [Laravel SSH](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh)

```
$commands[] = 'cat settings.xml';
SSH::run($commands, function($line)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($line);
    $xml->age = 30;
    $xml = $xml->asXML();
    echo $xml; //it shows that age is changed to 30
    SSH::run(array(
        "echo  ~/demo/ $xml > settings.xml"
    ));
});
```

```xml
<note>
 <to>Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
 <age>50</age>
</note>
```

The problem with the code is that saved file is empty(nothing inside it).

- The connection is made throw ssh key and logs in as root.
- The system is Ubuntu 16.04.02 x64
- Laravel v5.4.22
- Laravelcollective/remote v5.4.0 (ssh package)

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down.

Comment: I do not understand either. Why someone would downvote for no reason nor explain his action for it. It is not like "hey I need this code". Anyway, THANK you for correcting the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve it using **printf**. Here's the full working code

```php
$commands[] = 'cat settings.xml';
SSH::run($commands, function($line)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($line);
    $xml->age = 30;
    $xml = $xml->asXML();
    SSH::run(array(
        "printf '%s' '$xml'' > demo/settings.xml"
    ));
});
```